# Is it possible to customise Live Visual Tree in Visual Studio even more?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-tree

I'm working on a C# WPF application, based on some XAMLs. As I'm trying to do some modifications on the layout, I've decided to work with the Live Visual Tree.

At first, this is what I got:
[image: Situation at the start]

As you can imagine, this is rubbish: which `Grid` stands for what?

Now, after giving each `Grid` its `x:Name`, this is what I have:
[image: after entering "x:Name"]

This is far more readable and proves that customising the Live Visual Tree is possible.
Now I would like to customise "a bit" further: I would like to display the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` in the Live Visual Tree too.

Is this possible and how can I do this? I'm thinking about something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grd_Headers">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"><!-- flag_show_in_Live_Visual_Tree--></RowDefinition>
```

#### Edit: what about Blend?

As mentioned in [the URL concerning Blend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-blend-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), I have observed that the "Blend"-related checkbox was checked in Visual Studio installer:

[image]

However, when opening a XAML file while designing, I don't see the corresponding image of the `Tools` panel: my "Toolbox" looks as follows:

[image]

... which looks like a regular toolbox.
When checking the menu "View", "Other windows", I don't see anything called "Blend" or something.

What do I need to do in order to see any "Blend"-related tools?

Even after having downloaded and installed Blend, it looks like a simple Visual Studio in a dark mode, but the typical Blend GUI is not present, as can be seen from the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You know [Blend for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-blend-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: Visual tree contains visual elements, `RowDefinition` is not a visual element.

Comment: @Clemens: I tried to follow the instructions on the URL you referred to (as described in the edit of my question) but I don't see any blend-related things.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not opened the correct Blend for Visual Studio.

Please search for Blend for Visual Studio in the search bar of the taskbar first.

[image]

Then create wpf to see if it meets your requirements:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I thought is was some feature I needed to switch on inside Visual Studio, I had no idea it was a separate application.

Comment: Seems I was too fast accepting your answer: I have managed launching Blend, but as mentioned in the last edit of my question, it just looks like a simple dark mode without any new functionalities.